# CRUD operations for multiple related records in different tables from single view in MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I was hoping I could get some assistance on this functionality I am trying to achieve. I have searched, but i do not seem to be able to translate the examples/tutorials I have found to make it work in my own code.

For brevity, let's say I have 2 Models with a one to many relationship between the two. Let's say it is parents and children. One parent can have zero or many children. Each child can only have 1 parent:

```
namespace MyApp.Models
{
  public partial class Parent 
    {
      [Key]
      public int parent_id { get; set; }
      public string parent_name { get; set; }
      public string parent_address { get; set; }
      public ICollection<Child> Child { get; set; }
    }
  public partial class Child { get; set; }
    {
      [Key]
      public int child_id { get; set; }
      public int parent_id { get; set; }
      public string child_name { get; set; }
      public string child_allergies { get; set; }
      public virtual Parent parent { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

Entity created the tables in the database properly, assigning primary/foreign keys where they needed to be.

I put the common fields in a viewmodel to render them in my view:

```
using MyApp.Models;
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
  public class ParentChildViewModel
    {
      public int parent_id { get; set; }
      public string parent_name { get; set; }
      public string parent_address { get; set; }
      public string child_name { get; set; }
      public string child_allergies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I have my view written as below:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ParentChildViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parent_name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parent_name)
  </div>

  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.parent_address)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.parent_address)
  </div>

  <table id="child_table">
    @{ Html.RenderPartial("_children"); }
  </table>

  <div>
  <button id="add">Add Child</button>
  <button id="rem">Remove Child</button>
  </div>

  <div>
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
  </div>
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#add").click(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("BlankChRow")",
        cache: false,
        success: function (html) {
          $("#child_table").append(html);
        }
      });
    return false;
    });
    $("#rem").click(function () {
      $("#child_table tbody tr:last")
        .remove();
      return false;
    });
</script>
```

I created a partial view for the child so I can repeat those:

```
@model MyApp.ViewModels.ParentChildViewModel
@using (Html.BeginCollectionItem("children"))
{
<tr>
  <td>
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.child_name)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child_name)
  </div>
  </td>

  <td>
  <div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.child_allergies)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.child_allergies)
  </div>
  </td>
</tr>
}
```

Then, in my controller (this is where I am stuck):

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

public ActionResult BlankChRow()
{
  return PartialView("_children");
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
  return View(new ParentChildViewModel());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ParentChildViewModel pcvm)
{
  var parent = new Parent()
  {
    parent_id = pcvm.parent_id,
    parent_name = pcvm.parent_name,
    parent_address = pcvm.parent_address
  };
  var child = new Child()
  {
    parent_id = pcvm.parent_id,
    child_name = pcvm.child_name,
    child_allergies = pcvm.child_allergies
  };
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    db.Parent.Add(parent);
    db.Child.Add(child);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
return View(pcvm);
}
```

I have experimented a few different ways of doing this... but I am unable to get this working the way I would like. Ideally, the View can be brought up, and while they enter the Parent's data, they could add one or many children. The children that are added would each be their own record in the Child table/entity while having the appropriate parent_id.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Mudd, you should use C# naming conventions. Properties use PascalCase, e.g. `ParentName`. Conventions are technically a suggestion, but consistency is not. By your convention, `Parent.Child` should be `Parent.child`.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve. It sounds like you are going for one of those interfaces where you can enter parent data, then there's a section for child data, but after you add that and click confirm, the fields to add another child come up. Is that correct? Or are you just trying to loop through a list of children, as Jon suggested?

Comment: Sinjai, I forgot to include my submit button in the example code I used for my view.... What I am hoping to achieve is to be able to create a new parent record. While creating the parent record, multiple children can be added in the same view. Once they submit the form, I am hoping to have the parent and all children saved to db.

Comment: Are you looking to have some kind of "add child" button? I know of a couple different ways you could do this. Reiterating because you didn't say anything: I strongly recommend following C# conventions. It's a surprisingly powerful tool.

Comment: Sinjai, I will take your advice for the conventions under consideration. But to answer the question, yes. I would like to have a button to add a set of fields to create a child. I would like to be able to add multiple children to each parent.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you want to generate a list of children for a given parent but your viewmodel doesn't look so.

```
using MyApp.Models;
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
  public class ParentChildViewModel
    {
      public int parent_id { get; set; }
      public string parent_name { get; set; }
      public string parent_address { get; set; }
      public string child_name { get; set; }
      public string child_allergies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Try a viewmodel with a list of children. 
Something like this :

```
using MyApp.Models;
namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
  public class ParentChildViewModel
    {
      public int parent_id { get; set; }
      public string parent_name { get; set; }
      public string parent_address { get; set; }
      public IEnumerable<Child> children { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I'm supposing here that you just want to iterate over the list. That's why I use the IEnumerable interface instead of the IList interface.

To add a child in the list, you could call the "Create" function of your controller and pass the parent_id of the new child. 
In your controller you can therefore create a new child for a given parent in the database using your application context.

Once the database transaction done, you can create a new ParentChildViewModel and fulfill it with the corresponding children and return it to the view.

Comment: Thank you for your time. If I change the viewmodel to use IEnumerable<Child> instead of the individual field names for the child, how would I then include the child fields in the view? I apologize for my naivete.